# If player is initially colliding, jumping should only go straight up

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi I'm currently working on a third person controller and am having some issues with jumping when the player is colliding. Currently when the player is colliding with a cube but the user is trying to move in the direction of the cube the player will go in the direction the user was initially trying to go when the player is not anymore colliding (Midair). I want it so that when the user jumps when he is colliding, the player only goes straight up even if the player is not colliding on a higher point anymore. How would I achieve this? I have tried different things like using raycasts and colliders, but unfortunately without any luck.

The relevant script as I have it right now:

```
void Move(Vector2 inputDir, bool running)
{
    if (inputDir != Vector2.zero)
    {
        float targetRotation = Mathf.Atan2(inputDir.x, inputDir.y) * Mathf.Rad2Deg + cameraT.eulerAngles.y;
        transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.up * Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y, targetRotation, ref turnSmoothVelocity, GetModifiedSmoothTime(turnSmoothTime));
    }

    float targetSpeed = ((running) ? runSpeed : walkSpeed) * inputDir.magnitude;
    currentSpeed = Mathf.SmoothDamp(currentSpeed, targetSpeed, ref speedSmoothVelocity, GetModifiedSmoothTime(speedSmoothTime));

    velocityY += Time.deltaTime * gravity;

    Vector3 velocity = transform.forward * currentSpeed + Vector3.up * velocityY;
    controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);

    currentSpeed = new Vector2(controller.velocity.x, controller.velocity.z).magnitude;

    // Checks if player is not grounded and is falling

    if (GroundCheck())
    {
        velocityY = 0;
        anim.SetBool("onAir", false);
    }
    else
    {
        anim.SetBool("onAir", true);
    }
}

void JumpWalk()
{
    if (JumpCheck())
    {
        float jumpVelocity = Mathf.Sqrt(-2 * gravity * jumpHeightIdle);
        velocityY = jumpVelocity;
        anim.SetTrigger("JumpWalk");
        canJump = Time.time + 1.3f; //Delay after jump input
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some things to note:

- The player controller is moving (translating) your character according to a velocity variable controlled by user input.
- The player controller is detecting collision/intersection with a wall and moving your character away from the wall so that it is no longer intersecting.
- The player controller has no knowledge of the velocity variable, and therefore cannot change the velocity (only the position/translation).
- You are not explicitly handling the collision with the wall, and therefore you are not adjusting the velocity due to the collision with the wall.
- When the player is in the air but no longer touching the wall (due, most likely, to sliding against the wall diagonally) it resumes moves according to it's velocity without interference from the wall.

Therefore the player character resumes its original velocity since nothing has updated that variable.

You will need to handle the collision manually using the `void OnCollision(Collision collision)` method and update the velocity variable according to the collision data.

This will require your character to have a `RigidBody`, but to prevent the physics engine from competing with your player controller's movement (translation), that body will need to be kinematic.